# Complex Analysis-Taylor Series

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem
Show that if $f$ is an analytic function in the unite disc $\Bbb D $ such that $f(-z)=f(z)$ for each $ z \in \Bbb D $ then there is an analytic function $h$ such that $f(z)=h(z^2)$ for all $z\in \Bbb D $

By Taylor Series I could get 
$f(z)= f(0)+\dfrac{f^2(0)}{2!}z^2 + \dfrac{f^4(0)}{4!}z^4...$ but I am not sure how to continue in defining h, can u straight way say that since the power series in convergent there is analytic function or use $h(z)=f(z^{1/2})$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$h(w) = \sum_{k\ge 0}f^{(2k)}(0)\frac{w^k}{(2k)!},$$
then show that this function is holomorphic in the unit disc.